# Get input text from Wear OS

Tags: android, flutter, wear-os

Im trying to get text on Wear OS from activity and back result to Platform Channel. What the right way to wait and get result from activity?

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(
        flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
        channel
    ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
        myResult = result
        getInputText()
    }
}

private fun getInputText() {
    val inputText: String

    val remoteInputs: List<RemoteInput> = listOf(RemoteInput.Builder("quick_reply").setLabel("Quick reply").build())
    val intent: Intent = createActionRemoteInputIntent()
    putRemoteInputsExtra(intent, remoteInputs)
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
    inputText = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent).toString()

    myResult?.success(inputText)
}
```

Now my code does not wait when I get the result and in Flutter I immediately get null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution through onActivityResult. Here is the finished solution:

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(
        flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
        channel
    ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
        if (call.method == "selectInputType") {
            _result = result
            val remoteInputs: List<RemoteInput> =
                listOf(RemoteInput.Builder("quick_reply").setLabel("Quick reply").build())
            val intent: Intent = createActionRemoteInputIntent()
            putRemoteInputsExtra(intent, remoteInputs)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 9689)
        } else {
            result.notImplemented()
        }
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, result: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode != 9689)
        return super.onActivityResult(requestCode, result, intent)
    if (result == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val inputResult = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent)
        _result.success(inputResult.getCharSequence("quick_reply"))
    } else
        _result.error("RESULT_NOT_OK", "", "")
}
```